# Position of xtick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I enhance the appearance of the xtick labels (shift them to the top of the plotted lines.

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}           
 \usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
 \definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     xlabel={$t$(s)},
     grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     ylabel={$v(t)$},
     axis lines=left,
    scaled ticks=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    minor tick num=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2},


 xmin = 0, xmax =8,
    ymin = -0.5, ymax = 0.5,
    ytick={0,0.5},
    yticklabels={$0$,$V_m$},
    xtick= { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    xticklabels={0,$T/2$,$T$,$3T/2$,$2T$,$5T/2$,$3T$,$7T/2$,$4T$},
     x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=0,below}                        
            ]

     \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=50

,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0.5*x};
     \addplot[domain=1:2,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \addplot[domain=2:3,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {-0.5*(x-2)};
     \addplot[domain=3:4,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \addplot[domain=4:5,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0.5*(x-4)};
     \addplot[domain=5:6,samples=50,smooth,

lava, ultra thick] {0};
      \addplot[domain=6:7,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {-0.5*(x-6)};
     \addplot[domain=7:8,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (3,0) -- (3,-0.5);
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (5,0) -- (5,0.5);
        \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (7,0) -- (7,-0.5);

\end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code and explain what you mean by enhancing appearance. What look do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the height of a graph is `\axisdefaultheight`. I move the labels by half this height: `xticklabel style={yshift=.5*\axisdefaultheight}`

#### Update :

As noted by  @Torbjørn T. in his commentary, this solution becomes more general by using the pgf key  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}` instead of `\axisdefaultheight`.

```
xticklabel style={yshift=.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}           
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$t$(s)},
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    ylabel={$v(t)$},
    axis lines=left,
    scaled ticks=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    minor tick num=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2},
    xmin = 0, xmax =8,
    ymin = -0.5, ymax = 0.5,
    ytick={0,0.5},
    yticklabels={$0$,$V_m$},
    xtick= { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    xticklabels={0,$T/2$,$T$,$3T/2$,$2T$,$5T/2$,$3T$,$7T/2$,$4T$},
    x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=0,below},
    xticklabel style={yshift=.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}}                     
    ]
     \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0.5*x};
     \addplot[domain=1:2,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \addplot[domain=2:3,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {-0.5*(x-2)};
     \addplot[domain=3:4,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \addplot[domain=4:5,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0.5*(x-4)};
     \addplot[domain=5:6,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \addplot[domain=6:7,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {-0.5*(x-6)};
     \addplot[domain=7:8,samples=50,smooth,lava, ultra thick] {0};
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (3,0) -- (3,-0.5);
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (5,0) -- (5,0.5);
     \draw [ ultra thick, lava,dashed] (7,0) -- (7,-0.5);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `xticklabel style={yshift=.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}},` instead, `\axisdefaultheight` only works the the height of the axis is unchanged.

Comment: You are right, the solution becomes more general.